# What's the difference between Country Born and Mulatto people in the 18th century New England?

Tags: united-states, slavery, north-america, new-world

I have a history assignment and it's asking me to provide context of the table already provided that contains "background characteristics of New England Runaways."

To be specific, it states the following categories: African, Country born, Mulatto, Negro, and West Indies, along with percentages of runaways every ten years.

I'm a bit confused as to what the difference is between country born and mulatto people. Professor didn't include any information regarding the differences and I can't find much information about it online.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume the table you have been given is taken from [A Prince among Pretending Free Men: Runaway Slaves in Colonial New England Revisited](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Prince-among-Pretending-Free-Men%3A-Runaway-Slaves-Bly/cf24d9dbf7ced5b9037c9e3130c5e02f8572549b).  If so, that table appears as *Table 3* on page 98:

[image: Table - background characteristics of fugitives in Massachusetts]

---

- *African* slaves were slaves born in Africa.
- *Country born* slaves were born in the United States.
- *Mulatto* meant mixed race. Mulatto slaves were generally also *Country born*.  As Antonio T. Bly, the author of that paper, put it:

> "... mulatto fugitives proved the most peculiar of the countryborn lot. As social and racial outcasts they were a different kind of fugitive. Through no fault of their own, they embodied the taboo of interracial sex.

- *Negro* is fairly self-explanatory.
- *West Indies* indicated a slave from the West Indies.

---

To clarify some of the apparent confusion in the comments.

The categories are **not** exclusive.  This is made clear in that passage quoted from the paper above, where is states explicitly that "mulatto" fugitives were also "countryborn".

So, for example, in the 1730, 86% of the notices described the fugitive as "*Negro*", 4% described the fugitive as "*Mulatto*", etc.  But note that only 3% described the fugitive as "*Country born*" (although we should understand that the fugitives described as "*Mulatto*" were also "*Country born*", even though that wasn't explicitly stated on the notices).

---

The issue is how they were described in the fugitive notices (and so recorded in the database).  I note that the numbers are all rounded to the nearest integer, so there were also, presumably, other descriptive terms that were used so infrequently that they were not allocated a category by modern scholars.

The point being that the 17th-century slave-owners weren't picking a label from a prescriptive list, and the labels that were used weren't necessarily used with the precision that modern scholars would like.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you so much for clarifying this! I appreciate it!

Comment: More specifically, Mulatto means "half White, half black", at least in some instances. If a Mulatto had a child by a White person, the resulting child would have been a Quadroon.

Comment: @nick012000 and if they had a white partner the resulting child would have been Octaroon.

Comment: Hm. Actually, I find "Negro" not self-explanatory at all. If two "Africans" have a child born in the colonies, then it sounds like they would be "Country born". What *is* a "Negro"? (Incidentally, what's ["Creole"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creole) about *any* of the categories, except for "Mulatto"?)

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa  Possibly someone could fit two or more different categories at the same time.  A country born slave might be either negro or mulatto, a negro might be  either African or country born.   But it looks like all the categories are exclusive and nobody is in two categories.

Comment: I don't find this explanation very satisfying, inasmuch as it seems to indicate that the various categories are not all mutually exclusive.  Is it really a coincidence that the entries in each and every row add up to exactly 100% ?

Comment: @JohnBollinger  They are not mutually exclusive.  The table simply records the descriptive terms used by people when they advertised runaway slaves in Massachusetts in those decades.   Why would you expect different people to be consistent in their use of those terms?

Comment: @StephanKolassa "*Creole*" didn't come to mean "mixed-race" until later.  Originally it just meant "born in the colonies" (adopted from the French term). Consider, for example, the term "[Creoles of colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creoles_of_color)" which was originally used to distinguish non-white "creoles" from white "creoles" in Louisiana.

Comment: @sempaiscuba, the context and significance of the table are unclear from this answer.  If it indeed simply records descriptive terms from runaway slave advertisements then it would be helpful to add that.  However, I am inclined to think that there's more to it.  The fact that the entries in every row add up to exactly 100% suggests that the advertisements surveyed were *paritioned* into these categories, so that for the purposes of the table, at least, the categories are indeed exclusive.  That would affect how the table should be interpreted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's not in the answer, because that is not what was asked in the question.  They were indeed partitioned into those categories, but that was by 21st-century scholars, not by those who placed the advertisements in the 18th-century.  However, by all means, read the linked paper if anything remains unclear to you.

Comment: @nick012000 In general usage, the term "*mulatto*" meant simply "mixed race".  It continued to be used in that sense on the US census right up to 1920.  (For context, the terms “*quadroon*” and “*octoroon*” only appeared on the 1890 US census).  It is more common to see descriptions along the lines of "*A negro, between a black and a mulatto* ..." in adverts for runaway slaves.  Some examples are quoted in [Runaway Slave Advertisements from Loyalist Newspapers of the Maritime Colonies](https://cedar.wwu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1102&context=wwu_honors) by Sarah Elizabeth Chute.